# insert dynamic value into output file

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker

### Context

I have a service worker entrypoint which looks like this:

```js
{
  entry: {
    serviceWorker: './src/serviceWorker.ts'
  }
}
```

There are other entrypoints, but for this example I'm just showing the service worker entrypoint.

I want the contents of the service worker to change whenever any output file changes so that the browser will detect a service worker change (and can update to use the new version). I can use `stats.hash` for this.

### What I'm trying to do

When building the project with webpack, this like should be inserted into some place in the output file:

```js
/* hash: asdf70a89sd7f098as7d0f897a0 */
```

the hash will be whatever `hash` is in the webpack stats.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

I found out that the original plugin had [a lot of issues](https://web.archive.org/web/20210714230247/https://github.com/levp/wrapper-webpack-plugin/issues) and it wasn't working in production mode. I found a built in webpack plugin that works.

I used [BannerPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/) to do this.

I added this plugin to my webpack config:

```js
new BannerPlugin({
  banner: '/*@preserve [fullhash]*/',
  entryOnly: true,
  include: 'serviceWorker',
  raw: true
})
```

The header function adds a comment with the hash for the service worker file, and leaves other files how they are.

To include the comment in production build, I used the following minify options:

```js
new TerserPlugin({
  terserOptions: {
    format: {
      comments: /@preserve/i
    }
  },
  extractComments: /^\**!|@license|@cc_on/i
})
```

### Original Answer

I used [`wrapper-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/levp/wrapper-webpack-plugin) to do this.

I added this plugin to my webpack config:

```js
new WrapperPlugin({
  header: (fileName, { hash }) => {
    return fileName === 'serviceWorker.bundle.js' ? `/* hash: ${hash} */` : ''
  },
  afterOptimizations: true
})
```

The header function adds a comment with the hash for the service worker file, and leaves other files how they are.